How do I make a Next.js <Image> tag work with my AWS S3 Bucket Policy?
I have a Next.js app that I've deployed with Vercel and am using an AWS S3 Bucket to store photos that I want to be able to read only from my website.
My CORS policy is set to allow all traffic so it shouldn't affect anything:
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "POST",
            "PUT",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": [],
        "MaxAgeSeconds": 3000
    }
]

Here is my Bucket Policy:
{
  "Sid": "AllowReadFromWebsite",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": "*",
  "Action": "s3:GetObject",
  "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringLike": {
      "aws:Referer": [
        "https://my-domain.vercel.app/*",
        "https://my-domain.vercel.app/_next/image*"
      ]
    }
  }
}

This policy doesn't work with Next.js Image tags in production. I don't know exactly how it works but I think that the request to see the image doesn't come directly from my website domain but somehow uses the server or something with caching. If I use an img tag it works just fine. Also if I add http://localhost:3000 to the Bucket Policy and use it in dev it works with both Image and img tags. I don't know if the problem is with the Next.js Image tag or with Vercel or what. Maybe it has something to do with serverless. Does anyone have any experience with this? I ultimately want my photos stored in my bucket to only be readable from my website. How can I achieve this with Next.js Image tags? For now I'm using:
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowReadFromAnywhere",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}

Is this ill-advised? I don't care that much about security I just don't want people to be able to maliciously use up my Bandwidth.

Short
Recommendation:

Set up AWS CloudFront as CDN.
Restrict access to your S3 bucket to the CloudFront distribution.
Configure caching in your CloudFront distribution.
Configure HTTPS-only in your CloudFront distribution.
Adjust the asset URLs in your NextJS app.
(Optional) Set up rate limiting in AWS WAF for your CloudFront distribution.

See the long section for details and references.
Long
Without knowing details about your NextJS setup, I can imagine that the issue is with server side rending, the Image tag, and/or probably how vercel is working. You could enable access logging in your S3 bucket to troubleshoot the access to your bucket.
Also, S3 does not support HTTPS. Meaning, the request to your image could be blocked by the browser, if your website is mixing insecure HTTP requests and HTTPS. You can set up AWS CloudFront to serve assets from S3 over HTTPS and also cache the assets.
If I understood you correctly, rate limiting is an option for your requirement to control abuse.
For this use case I recommend setting up static file hosting with AWS S3 and AWS CloudFront (including caching), protected by AWS Web Application Firewall rate limiting.
Be aware of fine-tuning AWS WAF and of the costs (especially WAF).
Side note: faking any HTTP headers is simple, fake referrer tools exist. Don't rely on this level of security.
Even if your photos are only accessible over your website, an attacker could simply reload your website endlessly.
BTW, I have quite a similar setup, but I am using AWS resources only: server side rending with AWS Lambda functions instead of vercel, hosting static content in AWS S3, AWS CloudFront as a CDN. My S3 Bucket is not public though.
Describing how to set that up is out of scope here, but have a look at this guide Deploy Nextjs 13 app to AWS Lambda using AWS Serverless Application Model or look for similar guides.
